# With Laravel and 5.3 PHP Frameworks is CodeIgniter still suitable for PHP apps?

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel

The title says it all...

I've 2 years CI experience and with my own helpers, libraries and Sparks/GitHub for extra libraries I find it a good framework...

With seemingly everyone jumping ship to Laravel is CodeIgniter still suitable for app development at the moment or is it deprecated?

Is part of the reason everyone bashes it because it doesn't use static methods, and code ends up with $this everywhere and/or it doesn't use 5.3 features?

I'd appreciate any replies cos I have to start developing a new app in the next week...

Comment: I use it (CI) every now and again though I've been looking at fuelphp for no other reason than to expand my horizons, I understand CI 3.0 is on the way which might revive the beast

Answer (score 2):

All preference.

I would say 99% of hosts allow PHP 5.3+ (probably closer to 100% of all reliable hosts), so the backwards compatibility to old versions of PHP is useless, and can be seen as bloat.

Ultimately, it doesn't matter.  Newer frameworks take advantage of Autoloaders, Namespaces, Class Overloading, and some even have CRUD generators and DB migration tools.  Codeigniter is solid, still developed, and will get the job done.

With switching, there will be a longer development period due to learning new libraries and standards of the other framework.  Then again, learning a new framework is bound to increase your skill as a programmer.

Personally, I like Codeigniter only because it was my first framework I did a job with, but after moving on to other frameworks, Codeigniter feels lacking and certain aspects feel out of place.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out CodeIgniter does support DB migrations - I haven't personally used them, but they are there and one may infer from your comment that CI does not have this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter is good for small projects. But you can take a look at this [framework](http://fuelphp.com/). It has ORM, supports mongodb and redis etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look into [symfony2](http://symfony.com), if you feel CI is not the right choice anymore.

However, if you need to start developing next week I assume you have a deadline, which makes me recommend using the framework you're most comfortable with. If it's CI I'm sure you will get the job done in CI.

But honestly, this question is too vague to be answered. It really depends on your project if people can recommend sticking to CI or choosing another framework.